# GIT Permission Denied on password on push

Tags: git, ssh

I've seen similar questions, but none the same as this...

I'm trying to get my private repository on our new server working properly.  I setup the server and the git repository myself.  First time I have setup a git repository, and after reading a lot of variants on a theme, something easily could have gone astray.

After my first commit from my local Windows PC, I try:

```
git push origin master
```

It prompts me for my passphrase for key 'C:/Users/Me/.ssh/id_rsa.  Then it prompts me the git user password.  This always fails and after 3 tries, with the message

`"Permission denied (publickey,gssapi-keyex,gssapi-with-mic,password). fatal: Could not read from remote repository."`

I've checked and double checked that the paths are correct.  The keys seem to be in the right format and in the right places.  I've reset git's password on the server several times.  So, I'm running out of options.  Any ideas?

Comment: Why don't you try disabling all passwords first, then enabling them one by one to see which one is failing?

Comment: It would help if you linked to questions and answers that you've already taken a look at. Did you upload your public key to your private server?

Comment: If the passphrase for the key was wrong, it would ask me to retype it, which it doesn't.  So, it is the actual password to the account that is the failure point.  But it might not be password related.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out this was not a problem with git, or even ssh.  The domain owner set the DNS of subdomains properly, but not the main domain.  Once I started using one of the sub-domains, everything fell into place.  I'm still not sure why the passphrase was authenticated, but many mysteries in life.

However some of the below debugging tips helped.  for git diagnostics:

```
set GIT_TRACE=1
set GIT_CURL_VERBOSE=1
```

use -v for verbose on commands.

using ssh directly, led me to the problem, especially the -v option:

so using:

```
ssh -vT git@domain.com
```

I noticed that the IP address was different, which led to wonder how the dns was setup.

Comment: it doesn't work on my mac

Comment: @SeyedHosseinHosseinimotlagh - Did you set up the environment variables? Did the verbose option show any information?

Comment: I use docker-compose to run git on my remote server, but I forgot to expose ssh port. I solved it. thank you